# Question about boundary of set defined by a polynomial

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $p(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is is a polynomial of degree $n$. Define $M=\{z\, |\, \text{Re}\,p(z)<0\}$.

Why is $\partial M=\{z\, |\, \text{Re}\,p(z)=0\}$?

I have only read some basic analysis, but no topology. So just saying by continuity of $p(z)$ doesn't really explain it to me.

Further more, what more can be said about $\partial M$?

Comment: Intuitively, we can say that there is a region called $M$ in whcih the real part of $p(z)$ is positive, another region where it is negative. The line between them is where the real part of $p$ vanishes. To be more precise, you need at least a rigorous definition of $\partial M$, and for this, you need some basics in topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is similar to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352005/proving-that-f-big-partial-a-0-where-a-f-0). I'll do a sketch: let $z \in \partial M$. We use that $z \mapsto {\rm Re}(p(z))$ is continuous.

For every $n \geq 1$ there exists $r_n > 0$ such that $w_n \in B(z, r_n) \cap M$ implies $|{\rm Re}\,p(z) - {\rm Re}\,p(w_n)| < 1/n$. In other words: $$-\frac{1}{n} < {\rm Re}\,p(w_n) - \frac{1}{n} < {\rm Re}\,p(z),\,\forall\,n \geq 1 \implies \,{\rm Re}\,p(z)\geq 0.$$ Repeating the argument with $B(z,r_n)\cap M^c$ gives ${\rm Re}\,p(z) \leq 0$. So ${\rm Re}\,p(z) = 0$.